# Rename files in command loop

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file, cmd

I have a directory of PDFs that I need to rename according to a repeating sequence. In English, the command would go like this:

For each file in the directory, and in the order that the files are listed, alternate names between "Type 1", "Type 2" , "Type 3" until the each item has been renamed.

I'm hoping to do this in Powershell or on the command line.

Comment: yo, welcome to Stackoverflow... Can you paste the code you tried already? did you mean "...enumerate names between..." ?

Comment: You can only have one file named "Type 1", so your alternating strategy cannot work as you have described. You need to think more clearly and/or express your requirements more clearly. Also,this site is not intended for "here are my requirements, can you please provide code" type "questions". The goal is to get programming questions with answers that can help the general population, not just the OP.

Answer (score 1):

The ForEach-Object cmdlet accepts a script block for the -Begin argument which can be used to initialize a counter variable.  This variable can then be incremented on each iteration.

```
dir <directory_of_pdfs> | ForEach-Object -Begin { $i=1 } -Process { Rename-Item $_ "Type $($i++)" }
```

Comment: Please don't encourage "gimmie the codez" questions.

Comment: My bad. Will do Matt.